# How to get this message object from response in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, object, response

This is what is coming from Python:

```
[{'message': 'Invalid password.'}]
```

My jQuery which gets the response back:

```
console.log(response);

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

if (response) {

    var errorMessage = (response.message);

    console.log('errorMessage is:');
    console.log(errorMessage);
```

`console.log(response)` returns `[{"message": "Invalid password."}]`
I'm stuck on `response.message` which is being returned undefined. I tried getting it from my `obj` var too, but same results:

[image]

Any tips on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You parsed it as `obj`, so `obj.message`

Comment: tried that, also returning `undefined` for some reason :(

Comment: Maybe your JSON was invalid, so therefore couldn't be parsed by parseJSON()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just an object, it's an object in a larger array as is indicated with the square brackets. So to access it you'd actually need to say `obj[0].message`